# Zeitwerk: add custom namespace to /public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, autoload, zeitwerk

I have an app with the following structure:

```
- my_app
  - bin
  - config
  - packages
    - pack_name
      - priv
      - public
        - service_one
        - service_two
    - other_pack_name
```

*Note there is no app dir, because I'm using [packwerk](https://github.com/Shopify/packwerk)*

With the current configuration I access the services in `/public` directly with `ServiceOne` and `ServiceTwo` constants. Now, what I want to achieve is set those instead as `PackName::ServiceOne` and `PackName::ServiceTwo`. But this should only be forced for files inside `/public`.

How can I achieve this?

This is my current configuration:

```
# config/application.rb

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 6.0

    # packages
    config.paths.add 'packages', glob: '*/{*,*/concerns}', eager_load: true
    ...
  end
end
```

```
# config/initializers/zeitwerk.rb

Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    "my_wrapper" => "MyWrapper", # ActiveAdmin class
  )

  autoloader.ignore(Rails.root.join('packages/ops/admin'))
end
```

`service_one.rb` should look like:

```
module PackName
  class ServiceOne
  end
end
```

EDIT: I know this would solve the issue, but I'd like to avoid creating an extra directory `/pack_name` inside `/public` folder

Comment: I am not familiar with `packwerk`, but Zeitwerk allows you to define custom namespaces for specific root directories, documented here https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#custom-root-namespaces. In theory that is what you need, but I don't know if you can hook into the loader configuration to customize.

Comment: @XavierNoria in that example `ActiveJob::QueueAdapters` is an actual class, while here `PackName` is not. Do I forcefully need a pack_name.rb (or folder)? or there's a way around it?

Comment: it can be a module too. The only condition is that it is not reloadable. The same API enforces that in common scenarios by requiring the class or module object right there, before the autoloader is ready.